# Prevent paragraph ending before display equation in TeX4ht

Tags: paragraphs, tex4ht

I'm using TeX4ht and I noticed that the displayed equations always forces the current paragraph to end. For example, if I write:

```
We define
\[ x = 3 \]
and continue the discussion.
```

I would expect only one paragraph produced, but TeX4ht produces two (one before, and one after the equation).

Here is a minimal working example, to be compiled first with `latex`, then with `tex4ht`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xhtml,mathml]{tex4ht}

\begin{document}
We define
\[ x = 3 \]
and continue the discussion.
\end{document}
```

Any idea of a workaround, or a solution?

(I think that I figured out that the TeX4ht file which produces those paragraph ending is `html-mml.4ht`, but I'm not sure how to fix it)

Answer (score 3):

You might add the following after `\begin{document}` and rerun:

```
\catcode`\:=11
\catcode`\@=11
\Configure{[]}
  {\SaveEndP
   \Configure{@math}{display="block"}%
   \csname a:mathml[]\endcsname
   \DviMath\Tg<\a:mathml mrow\Hnewline>$$\DisplayMathtrue }
  {$$\Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\EndDviMath\csname b:mathml[]\endcsname}
\catcode`\:=12
\catcode`\@=12
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a good start, but it does not quite work. First, after the equation, a `p` tag is produced, which should not be there. Second, that solution works only for the `\[\]` environment, not for the `equation` environment, for example...